# How to use C# Generics to limit method to integer types and still use operators

Tags: c#, generics, integer

Can I use generics to create a method that takes integer types, and is still be able to do basic mathematical operations inside the method on those types?

My situation: I wrote a method that takes a value of type int and returns whether the value is prime or not. I later needed that method to work on larger numbers, so I changed the input type to Int64, but this has a negative impact on speed. Efficiency is very important here.

I knew very little about generics, but thought it would prevent me from having two nearly identical overloaded methods. I am however unable to get it to work, and I don't know if it's because I'm trying to incorrectly use Generics, or if I have a syntax error.

I thought that limiting the types to "int" and "UInt64" would allow me to use mathematical operators such as '>' and '%' inside the method, but that doesn't seem to work.

Code for reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests whether a number is prime.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsPrime<T>(T numToTest) where T: int, UInt64
    {
        List<T> primeList = new List<T>();
        primeList.Add(2); // Give the list an initial prime number. error here when using generics.
        return IsPrime(numToTest, primeList);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tests whether a number is prime. Takes an initial list of primes as input to speed the method up.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsPrime<T>(T numToTest, List<T> primeList)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        T limit = (T)Math.Sqrt(numToTest); //error here when using generics.

        primeList = Prime.AllPrimesUnder(limit, primeList); // If we don't have enough primes to properly test the number, get more.

        foreach (T prime in primeList)
        {
            if (prime > limit) //error here when using generics.
                break;

            if (numToTest % prime == 0) //error here when using generics.
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isPrime;
    }
```

The only alternative I know of is to have:

```
public static bool IsPrime<int>(int numToTest, List<int> primeList)
public static bool IsPrime<UInt64>(UInt64 numToTest, List<UInt64> primeList)
public static bool IsPrime<BigInteger>(BigInteger numToTest, List<BigInteger> primeList)
```

etc etc...

Comment: `where T: int, UInt64` means where T is both `int` **and** `UInt64`, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, that would explain why it doesn't currently work. Before I go spend another couple hours searching and trying to get Generics to do what I think it should do, could you spoil the ending and tell me if what I want is even possible?

Comment: Can't you simply use the biggest integer for IsPrime definition and then cast that type when calling it?

Comment: You can't.  Such a generic constraint does not exist.  C# generics stink in this regard.  You can however finagle a solution using this library: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: If I understand this correctly then, specifiying multiple types for generic input isn't possible, which means that you'd never specify 'int' or 'UInt64' as they have no subtypes. Since I'm looking for speed, I guess overloaded methods with just a type difference is probably the easiest to implement and fastest to execute while still being moderately maintainable.

Comment: @pinckerman that would work, but would be slow since casting is slow. It would also require more than the one cast, as any code that made use of this method would have to cast to a BigInteger just to use it.

Comment: You can cast to `dynamic` and perform the operators.

Comment: what do you expect to get when you divide two T's? still a T? so if it's int's, would it be truncated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword with .NET 4.0

```
public static T Add<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return (T)((dynamic)x+(dynamic)y);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a=Add(10, 11);
    long b=Add(34L, 23L);
    uint c=Add(4u, 15u);
}
```

and even with custom types

```
public struct MyInt
{
    public static MyInt operator+(MyInt a, MyInt b)
    {
    }
}

{
    MyInt d=new MyInt(...);
    MyInt e=new MyInt(...);
    MyInt f=Add(d, e);
}
```

Comment: That answer works! I'd mark yours as the answer but apparently I don't have the rep yet. Unfortunately for me, the use of dynamic is killing the execution time worse that I would have thought. On a couple test numbers the version using dynamic ran 10x slower, even though I can see at run time they are both using the same types.

Comment: If you want speed then you need to `emit` opcodes. See this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10780/Operator-Overloading-with-Generics) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use any of these:

- `dynamic`
- Expression trees
- `DynamicMethod`

because they're all very slow compared to integer arithmetic (they use delegates).

Your best bet is to make an assembly in MSIL with arithmetic functions like `Add`, `Subtract`, etc., then call those from your C# code.

#### In fact, it turns out I've done your work for you already:

```
// Compile with:
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ilasm.exe Arithmetic.il /dll

.assembly extern mscorlib
{
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )
    .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly Arithmetic
{
}
.module Arithmetic.dll
.subsystem 0x0003


.class public abstract auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit Helper.Arithmetic
             extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig static !!T Or<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        or
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T And<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        and
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Xor<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        xor
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Not<T>(!!T val) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  1
        ldarg.0
        not
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Add<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        add
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T AddOverflow<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        add.ovf
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T AddOverflowUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        add.ovf.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Subtract<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        sub
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T SubtractOverflow<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        sub.ovf
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T SubtractOverflowUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        sub.ovf.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Multiply<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        mul
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T MultiplyOverflow<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        mul.ovf
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T MultiplyOverflowUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        mul.ovf.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Divide<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        div
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T DivideUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T Remainder<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        rem
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T RemainderUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        rem.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool Equals<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsLessThan<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsLessThanUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsLessThanOrEqualTo<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsLessThanOrEqualToUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt.un
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsGreaterThanUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsGreaterThanOrEqualToUnsigned<T>(!!T a, !!T b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt.un
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftLeft<T>(!!T a, int32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shl
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftLeft<T>(!!T a, uint32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shl
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftLeft<T>(!!T a, native int b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shl
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftLeft<T>(!!T a, native uint b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shl
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRight<T>(!!T a, int32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRight<T>(!!T a, uint32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRight<T>(!!T a, native int b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRight<T>(!!T a, native uint b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRightUnsigned<T>(!!T a, int32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRightUnsigned<T>(!!T a, uint32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRightUnsigned<T>(!!T a, native int b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T ShiftRightUnsigned<T>(!!T a, native uint b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        shr.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static native uint DivideCeiling(native uint a, native uint b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i4.1
        conv.u
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static uint32 DivideCeiling(uint32 a, uint32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i4.1
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static uint64 DivideCeiling(uint64 a, uint64 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i8     0x1
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static native int DivideCeiling(native int a, native int b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i4.1
        conv.i
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static int32 DivideCeiling(int32 a, int32 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i4.1
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static int64 DivideCeiling(int64 a, int64 b) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  4
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldc.i8     0x1
        sub.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ldarg.1
        div.un
        ret
    }


    .method public hidebysig static !!T Lerp<T>(!!T min, !!T weight, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  3
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldarg.0
        sub
        ldarg.2
        mul
        add
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T LerpOverflow<T>(!!T min, !!T weight, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  3
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldarg.0
        sub.ovf
        ldarg.2
        mul.ovf
        add.ovf
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static !!T LerpOverflowUnsigned<T>(!!T min, !!T weight, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  3
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        ldarg.0
        sub.ovf.un
        ldarg.2
        mul.ovf.un
        add.ovf.un
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsBetween<T>(!!T 'value', !!T min, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.2
        cgt
        or
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsBetweenUnsigned<T>(!!T 'value', !!T min, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        clt.un
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.2
        cgt.un
        or
        ldc.i4.0
        ceq
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsStrictlyBetween<T>(!!T 'value', !!T min, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.2
        clt
        and
        ret
    }

    .method public hidebysig static bool IsStrictlyBetweenUnsigned<T>(!!T 'value', !!T min, !!T max) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack  2
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        cgt.un
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.2
        clt.un
        and
        ret
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution which involes calling dynamic methods and emitting op-codes. Fortunately others have done a lot of work on this fiels and I can compiled a library that simplifies things tremendously.

Please pick up the source code for `Static<T>` from  http://ideone.com/IfiSCo to allow you to make calls like this:

```
/*
 * This file provides dynamic invocation of method, fields and properties
 * based on IL code generation.
 * 
 * This code was heavily influenced by 
 * 
 * a) Keith Farmer's Operator Overloading with Generics at 
 *      http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/genericoperators.asp
 *      
 * b) Douglas Gregor and Andrew Lumsdaine Operator<T> class for use in MPI
 *      environments, licensed under http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt
 *      http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/svn/
 * 
 */
public class Static<T> 
{
    // code emited for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the add operator for type <typeparamref name="T"/> and <typeparamref name="T"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static Func<T, T, T> Add { get { return Operator(BinaryOperator.op_Addition); } }
}
class Program
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public readonly int x;
        public MyStruct(int x) { this.x=x; }
        public static MyStruct operator+(MyStruct a, MyStruct b)
        {
            return new MyStruct(a.x+b.x);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a=Static<int>.Add(1, 2);
        uint b=Static<uint>.Add(1u, 2u);
        long c=Static<long>.Add(1U, 2U);
        MyStruct d = new MyStruct(1);
        MyStruct e = new MyStruct(2);
        MyStruct f=Static<MyStruct>.Add(d, e);
        // will result in f.x=3
    }
}
```